# How do I measure the strength of a password?

Tags: php, javascript, password-protection

I was looking for an effective algorithm that can give me an accurate idea of how strong a password is.

I found that several different websites use several different algorithms as I get different password strength ratings on different websites.

Comment: Is "righteous" really the word you wanted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has grown to my general brain dump of best practices for working with passwords in PHP/MySQL.
The ideas presented here are generally not my own, but the best of what I've found to date.

---

Ensure you are using SSL for all operations involving user information.  All pages that involve these forms should check they are being called via HTTPS, and refuse to work otherwise.

You can eliminate most attacks by simply limiting the number of failed logins allowed.

Allow for relatively weak passwords, but store the number of failed logins per user and require a captcha or password verification by email if you exceed it.  I set my max failures to 5.

Presenting login failures to the user needs to be carefully thought out as to not provide information to attackers.
A failed login due to a non existent user should return the same message as a failed login due to a bad password.  Providing a different message will allow attackers to determine valid user logins.

Also make sure you return exactly the same message in the event of a failure for too many logins with a valid password, and a failure with too many logins and a bad password.  Providing a different message will allow attackers to determine valid user passwords.  A fair number of users when forced to reset their password will simply put it back to what it was.

Unfortunately limiting the number of logins allowed per IP address is not practical.  Several providers such as AOL and most companies proxy their web requests.  Imposing this limit will effectively eliminate these users.

---

I've found checking for dictionary words before submit to be inefficient as either you have to send a dictionary to the client in javascript, or send an ajax request per field change.  I did this for a while and it worked ok, but didn't like the traffic it generated.

Checking for inherently weak passwords minus dictionary words IS practical client side with some simple javascript.

After submit, I check for dictionary words, and username containing password and vice versa server side.  Very good dictionaries are readily downloadable and the testing against them is simple.  One gotcha here is that to test for a dictionary word, you need to send a query against the database, which again contains the password.  The way I got around this was to encrypt my dictionary before hand with a simple encryption and end positioned SALT and then test for the encrypted password.  Not ideal, but better than plain text and only on the wire for people on your physical machines and subnet.

Once you are happy with the password they have picked encrypt it with PHP first, then store.  The following password encryption function is not my idea either, but solves a number of problems.  Encrypting within PHP prevents people on a shared server from intercepting your unencrypted passwords.  Adding something per user that won't change (I use email as this is the username for my sites) and add a hash (SALT is a short constant string I change per site) increases resistance to attacks.  Because the SALT is located within the password, and the password can be any length, it becomes almost impossible to attack this with a rainbow table.
Alternately it also means that people can't change their email and you can't change the SALT without invalidating everyone's password though.

EDIT:  I would now recommend using [PhPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) instead of my roll your own function here, or just forget user logins altogether and use [OpenID](http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/) instead.

```
function password_crypt($email,$toHash) {
  $password = str_split($toHash,(strlen($toHash)/2)+1);
  return hash('sha256', $email.$password[0].SALT.$password[1]); 
}
```

My Jqueryish client side password meter.  Target should be a div.  It's width will change between 0 and 100 and background color will change based on the classes denoted in the script.  Again mostly stolen from other things I've found:

```
$.updatePasswordMeter = function(password,username,target) {
$.updatePasswordMeter._checkRepetition = function(pLen,str) {
res = ""
for ( i=0; i<str.length ; i++ ) {
    repeated=true;
    for (j=0;j < pLen && (j+i+pLen) < str.length;j++)
        repeated=repeated && (str.charAt(j+i)==str.charAt(j+i+pLen));
    if (j<pLen) repeated=false;
    if (repeated) {
        i+=pLen-1;
        repeated=false;
    }
    else {
        res+=str.charAt(i);
    };
};
return res;
};
var score = 0;
var r_class = 'weak-password';
//password < 4
if (password.length < 4 || password.toLowerCase()==username.toLowerCase()) { 
target.width(score + '%').removeClass("weak-password okay-password good-password strong-password"
).addClass(r_class);
  return true;
} 
//password length
score += password.length * 4;
score += ( $.updatePasswordMeter._checkRepetition(1,password).length - password.length ) * 1;
score += ( $.updatePasswordMeter._checkRepetition(2,password).length - password.length ) * 1;
score += ( $.updatePasswordMeter._checkRepetition(3,password).length - password.length ) * 1;
score += ( $.updatePasswordMeter._checkRepetition(4,password).length - password.length ) * 1;
//password has 3 numbers
if (password.match(/(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/))  score += 5; 

//password has 2 symbols
if (password.match(/(.*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~].*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~])/)) score += 5; 

//password has Upper and Lower chars
if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  score += 10; 

//password has number and chars
if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  score += 15; 
//
//password has number and symbol
if (password.match(/([!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  score += 15; 

//password has char and symbol
if (password.match(/([!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~])/) && password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/))  score += 15; 

//password is just a nubers or chars
if (password.match(/^\w+$/) || password.match(/^\d+$/) )  score -= 10; 

//verifing 0 < score < 100
score = score * 2;
if ( score < 0 )  score = 0;
if ( score > 100 )  score = 100;
if (score > 25 ) r_class = 'okay-password';
if (score > 50  ) r_class = 'good-password';
if (score > 75 ) r_class = 'strong-password';
target.width(score + '%').removeClass("weak-password okay-password good-password strong-password"
).addClass(r_class);
return true;
};
```

Comment: -1 for security through obscurity. While it is true you could do this, it is a poor practice to promote.

Comment: I do both.  Relatively weak translates into 8 characters, requiring alpha, numeric, and one punctuation.  My JS for this is not available as I'm at work.

Comment: -1, brute force isn't just about preventing them from brute forcing your actual login (that's trivial). It's about preventing them from intercepting the hashed password and then without interacting with your servers, using/building a rainbow table to find out what password hashes to that. Then they login once to your site, and you allow it because it's the very first attempt.

Comment: rainbow tables are virtually useless provided you salt your hashed passwords, which I do.

Comment: @Daren: I voted down based on you very limited solution that only included a brute force lock. Expand your answer and I could easily change the vote. However, giving a small, terrible, piece of advice is still terrible advice

Comment: I don't agree with your all your methods, but this obviously has some pretty promising potential (at the very least in an academic sense) for checking internal patterns. It's a little bulky, but if the steel-toed boot fits... +1

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally you want to prevent to major types of attacks

- Dictionary attacks
- Brute force attacks

To prevent the first, you want to consider passwords containing common words weak.  To prevent the second, you want to encourage passwords of reasonable length (8+ characters is common) and with a reasonably large character set (include letters, numbers, and special characters).  If you consider lower case and upper case letters to be different, that increases the character set substantially.  However, this creates a usability issue for some user communities so you need to balance that consideration.

A quick google search turned up solutions that account for brute force attacks (complex password) but not for dictionary attacks.  PHP Password Strength Meter from [this list of strength checkers](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/) runs the check server-side, so it could be extended to check a dictionary.

EDIT:

By the way... you should also limit the number of login attempts per user.  This will make both types of attacks less likely.  Effective but not-user-friendly is to lock an account after X bad attempts and require a password reset.  More user friendly but more effort is to throttle time between login attempts.  You can also require [CAPTCHA](http://www.captcha.net/) after the first few login attempts (which is something that Stack Overflow requires after too many edits, or for very new users).

Comment: problem was that how do I know what amount of importance to give to which part of protection? as in, Which kind of attack should be taken care of more seriously?

Comment: I have personally cracked passwords using both dictionary and brute force attacks (as part of internal security audits).  You need to account for both basic types of attacks to be reasonably safe.

Comment: Also check to prevent common easy-to-guess things like: a) not to use password as password, not to use their username as their password, etc.

Comment: Added a note about another aspect of password security.

Comment: you can store a dictionary, or common weak password in a table on the database and just do a quick SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dict WHERE dict.phrase = 'blah' to check for a weak dictionary password.

Comment: +1 for great information from a seamingly reliable source. I'd also suggest you wiki this for a more collaborative effort.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you probably want to use Regular Expressions to validate the length and complexity of the password.

A good example doing this using javascript can be found here:

http://marketingtechblog.com/programming/javascript-password-strength/

Comment: This misses the "common word" (dictionary) attack.

Comment: If you require numbers and non-alphanumeric characters you inherently cannot have a "word" of any kind.

Comment: @brendan Not true. You'll see users pick passwords like 'Password1!', which complies with the common rules, yet is easy to brute-force since most users will simply add the required characters to the end of something they can easily remember. Most dictionaries contain those obvious variations.

Answer (score 3):

As Daren Schwenke pointed it out, **you'd better work on the security yourself and not put this in the user hands**.

But it's good to provide some hints to the user of how strong his password is, because **the best way to get a password is still social engenering**.

So you can hack a little client side script that checks the user password strenght as a courtesy indicator, in real time. It blocks nothing, but gives him a good warm feeling when it turns green :-)

Basically what you must check is commom sense : check if the password contains letters, numbers and non alphabetical caracters, in a reasonable quantity.

You can hack your own algo very easily : just make 10 / 10 mark :

- 0 is a zero lenght password;
- +2 for every 8 caracters in the password (15 is supposed to be a safe lenght);
- +1 for the use of a letter, +2 for the use of 2 letters;
- +1 for the use of a number, +2 for the use of 2 numbers;
- +1 for the use of a non alphabetical caracters, +2 for 2.

You don't need to check for godlike passwords (are there capitalized letters, where are positioned the special caracters, etc), your users are not in the bank / military / secret service / monthy python movies industry, are they ?

You can code that in an hour in without crazy javascript skills.

And anyway, valid the password and move all the security code on the server side. If you can delegate authentification (e.g : open ID), even better.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't Roll-Your-Own!

[Cryptography experts discourage roll-your-own cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign) for reasons that should be obvious.

For the very same reasons, one should not attempt to roll his own solution to the problem of measuring a password's strength; it is very much a cryptographic problem.

Don't get into the ugly business of authoring some massive regular expression for this purpose; you will likely fail to account for several factors that influence a password's overall strength.

### It's a Difficult Problem

There is considerable difficulty inherent to the problem of measuring a password's strength. The more research I perform on this subject, the more I realize that this is a "unidirectional" problem; that is, one cannot measure the "difficulty" (computational cost) of cracking a password *efficiently*. Rather, it is more efficient to provide complexity requirements and measure the password's ability to meet them.

When we consider the problem logically, a "crackability index" doesn't make much sense, as convenient as it sounds. There are so many factors that drive the calculation, most of which relate to the computational resources devoted to the cracking process, so as to be impractical.

Imagine pitting [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) (or a similar tool) against the password in question; it might take days to crack a decent password, months to crack a good password, and until the sun burns-out to crack an exceptional password. This is not a practical means by which to measure password strength.

Approaching the problem from the other direction is far more manageable: if we supply a set of complexity requirements, it's possible to judge the relative strength of a password very quickly. Obviously, the supplied complexity requirements must evolve over time, but there are far fewer variables for which to account if we approach the problem in this way.

### A Viable Solution

There is a standalone utility available from Openwall entitled [`passwdqc`](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/) (presumably, standing for *Password Quality Checker*). Openwall developer, Solar Designer, does appear to be a bona fide cryptography expert (his works speak for themselves), and so is qualified to author such a tool.

For my particular use-case, this is a far more attractive solution than using an ill-conceived JavaScript snippet living in some dark corner of the Web.

Establishing parameters for your particular needs is the hardest part. The implementation is the easy part.

### A Practical Example

I offer a simple implementation in PHP to provide a jump-start. Standard disclaimers apply.

This example assumes that we're feeding an entire list of passwords to the PHP script. It goes without saying that if you are doing this with real passwords (e.g., those dumped out of a password manager), extreme caution should be exercised with regard to password-handling. Simply writing the unencrypted password dump to disk jeopardizes the security of your passwords!

`passwords.csv`:

```
"Title","Password"
"My Test Password","password123"
"Your Test Password","123456!!!"
"A strong password","NFYbCoHC5S7dngitqCD53tvQkAu3dais"
```

`password-check.php`:

```
<?php

//A few handy examples from other users:
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#117692

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('passwords.csv'), [',']);

array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});

//Remove column header.

array_shift($csv);

//Define report column headers.

$results[] = [
    'Title',
    'Result',
    'Exit Code',
];

$i = 1;

foreach ($csv as $p) {
    $row['title'] = $p['Title'];

    //If the value contains a space, it's considered a passphrase.

    $isPassphrase = stristr($p['Password'], ' ') !== false ? true : false;

    $cmd = 'echo ' . escapeshellarg($p['Password']) . ' | pwqcheck -1 min=32,24,22,20,16 max=128';

    if ($isPassphrase) {
        $cmd .= ' passphrase=3';
    }
    else {
        $cmd .= ' passphrase=0';
    }

    $output = null;
    $exitCode = null;

    $stdOut = exec($cmd, $output, $exitCode);

    //Exit code 0 represents an unacceptable password (not an error).
    //Exit code 1 represents an acceptable password (it meets the criteria).

    if ($exitCode === 0 || $exitCode === 1) {
        $row['result'] = trim($stdOut);
        $row['exitCode'] = $exitCode;
    }
    else {
        $row['result'] = 'An error occurred while calling pwqcheck';
        $row['exitCode'] = null;
    }

    $results[$i] = $row;

    $i++;
}

$reportFile = 'report.csv';

$fp = @fopen($reportFile, 'w');

if ($fp !== false) {
    foreach ($results as $p) {
        fputcsv($fp, $p);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
else {
    die($reportFile . ' could not be opened for writing (destination is not writable or file is in use)');
}

exit;
```

Resultant `report.csv`:

```
Title,Result,"Exit Code"
"My Test Password","Bad passphrase (too short)",1
"Your Test Password","Bad passphrase (too short)",1
"A strong password",OK,0
```

### Wrapping-Up

I have yet to find a more thorough solution on the Web; needless to say, I welcome any other recommendations.

Obviously, this approach is not ideal for certain use-cases (e.g., a "password strength meter" implemented "client-side"). Even so, it would be trivial to make an AJAX call to a server-side resource that returns a pass/fail response using the approach outlined above, but such an approach should assume the potential for abuse (e.g., DoS attacks) and would require secure communication between client and server, as well as acceptance of the risks associated with transmitting the un-hashed password.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a specific algorithm to check the strengh of a password. What we do is we define several criterion and when the password respect a criteria, we add 1 to its score. When the password reach a threshold, the password is strong. Otherwise it is weak.

You can define many different level of strengh if with different throeshold, or you can define different value for a specific criteria. For example, if a password has 5 character, we add 1, but if it got 10, then we add 2.

here is a list of criterion to check for

Length (8 to 12 is ok, more is better)
Contains lowercase letter
Contains uppercase letter
The upper case letter is NOT the first one.
Contains number
Contains symbols
the last character is NOT a human like symbol (ex : . or !)
Does not look like a dictionnary word. Some wise password crack contains library of word and letter substitutes (like Library --> L1br@ry )

Hope that help.